# How can i change "oe_chatter" log comments in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo-10

I've created a custom module for uploading some documents against an employee in `Odoo 10`. And now i am trying to use "oe_chatter" for logs purpose.

When i click on save, log is coming as :

> Note by Administrator - 2 minutes ago
>
> hr.documents created

How can i change this to "Employee Document is created" ?

This is my code :

```
class HrDocuments(models.Model):
    _name = 'hr.documents'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']



<div class="oe_chatter">
                        <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
                        <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **_description = "Employee Document is created"** after **_inherit**